# grouping array elements according to other array elements

Tags: php, arrays, count, grouping

start with something like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'ccc',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  )
)
```

Then group array elements with index 'lo', counting values of 'co' which accompany them, to get eventually something similar to:

```
array (
  aaa => 2,
  bbb => 2,
  ccc => 1
)
```

Comment: So, you want us to do your work for you? Please show us [what have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: a foreach loop would bbe a good start, what have you tried?

Comment: he has enough repetitions to do him a little favor ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others about showing the code that you've tried so far. Having said that, this should work:

```
$array = array (
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  ),
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'ccc',
  ),
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  )
);

$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $a){
  if(!array_key_exists($a['lo'], $new_array)){
    $new_array[$a['lo']] = intval($a['co']);
  }else{
    $new_array[$a['lo']] = $new_array[$a['lo']] + intval($a['co']);
  }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

We're cycling through the array, creating a new array key if one doesn't exist, and adding to the array key value with the number specified in `'co'` if it already exists. You may want some additional checks to be sure that `'co'` and `'lo'` exist as array keys in the original array before trying to parse/add them to your new array.

As a side note, there is no need to specify the keys of your original array as numbers because  arrays are automatically indexed. Note that I have removed these numbers when declaring the array.

Comment: Also for the first statement ;-) $new_array[$a['lo']] = intval($a['co']);

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
$dataArray = array (
    0 =>
    array (
        'co' => '1',
        'lo' => 'aaa',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
        'co' => '1',
        'lo' => 'bbb',
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
        'co' => '1',
        'lo' => 'ccc',
    ),
    3 =>
    array (
        'co' => '1',
        'lo' => 'aaa',
    ),
    4 =>
    array (
        'co' => '1',
        'lo' => 'bbb',
    )
);

$finalResults = array();

foreach($dataArray as $data){
    if(isset($finalResults[$data['lo']])){
        $finalResults[$data['lo']]++;
    }else{
        $finalResults[$data['lo']] = 1;
    }
}


print_r($finalResults);
```

Comment: co is the count i think you should sum it up

Answer (score 0):

Here you are ;-)

```
$in=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'ccc',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'aaa',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'co' => '1',
    'lo' => 'bbb',
  )
);

$out= array();

for($i=0;$i<count($in);$i++)
{
    $out[$in[$i]['lo']]=0;
}

for($i=0;$i<count($in);$i++)
{
    $out[$in[$i]['lo']]+=$in[$i]['co'];
}

print_r($out);
```